# Open Anchor Output channels on CoreLightning

Tags: lightning-network, core-lightning, ln-opening-channels

I want to open a channel from my CoreLightning node to my LND node, and I want that channel to use anchor outputs to be used for the channel closing later on.

How can I enforce my CoreLightning node to create Anchor Outputs? Right now it just opens a "legacy" channel.

Context: I'm using nigiri on REGTEST

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [`experimental-anchors` option](https://github.com/ElementsProject/lightning/blob/master/doc/lightningd-config.5.md#experimental-options) on `lightningd` to enable experimental support for anchor output channels on Core Lightning.